# Does there exist a continous function $f(t)$ on $[0,1]$ for which $\int_0^1 t^3 f(t) dt = 0$?

Tags: integration, continuity

Does there exist a continous function $f(t)$ on $[0,1]$ for which $\int_0^1 t^3 f(t) dt = 0$?
Or can you provide a proof otherwise?

Comment: Do you mean $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ or $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$?

Comment: First one, $f(t) \in C[0,1]$

Comment: What's wrong with the zero function?

Comment: It is part of a larger question where i had to prove or disprove the orthogonal compliment was {0}, this function $f(t)=1-\frac{5}{4}t$ is a counterexample

Comment: There must be: take two random (continuous) functions $f$ and $g$ and look at all possible combinations $\lambda f + \mu g$.

In more abstract terms, $f \mapsto \int_0^1 t^3\, f(t)\, dt$ is a linear form, so its kernel is huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the trivial case which @alan points out, try an infinite family $f(t) = 1 - kt^n$, $n$ a positive integer. Solve for $k$.

Comment: I'm not sure if that'll stay within $C[0,1]$(Which is something he added in the comments)

Comment: $C[0,1]$ has co-domain all the reals not just the interval $[0.1]$, so we're good.

Comment: Ahh, right. I forgot

Answer (score 4):

Sure,  if you don't mind trivial cases.   $f(t)=0$.
If you want nontrivial,  I'd actually have to think about it :).

Answer (score 1):

Since $\int_0^1 t^3 dt = \frac14$, take any continuous $f_0$ (non-constant for more fun), and put $f:t\mapsto f_0(t)-c$ where $c=4\int_0^1 t^3 f_0(t) dt$.